# QuickBooks Credit card info always shows 12 month as an expiry month

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am using nSoftware to interact with QuickBooks. Whenever I try to update or insert Credit Card Expiry month, QuickBooks ignores month and always takes 12 as an expiry month. However Expiry years works fine. I tried updating Expiry Month from QuickBooks client interface also but that also takes 12 as an expiry month. For example, if I give expiry month as "4", QuickBooks ignores it and shows 12. Is there any setting to be done in QuickBooks?

Dev Environment:- ASP.Net 4.0, C#

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why QuickBooks will not let you update the expiration month. As long as your code looks something like the following, everything should update fine:

```cs
nsoftware.InQB.Customer customer1 = new nsoftware.InQB.Customer();
customer1.GetByName("Test Customer");

QBCard card = new QBCard();
card.ExpMonth = 8;
card.ExpYear = 2015;
customer1.CreditCard = card;

customer1.Update();
```

That said, the fact that you are also unable to update this within the QuickBooks UI makes 
me wonder if this is a QuickBooks issue. Is this something that recently started happening? You may need to contact Intuit to see if there is a QuickBooks setting that needs to be changed.

Additionally, in the future, you can contact /n software's support department directly by email at support@nsoftware.com. This will ensure that you get a prompt reply to your question. :)